# Import ppplus-library for rendering payment wall via given Link in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, nativescript

Is it possible to import a given JS-Library (in my case it would be https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js from [this .pdf file](https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/emea/de/de/paypal-plus-center/PayPal_PLUS_integration_guide.pdf) chapter 8.1 - "Integrating the payment wall")?

The text tells me the following:

1) Include JS library:

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Define a placeholder DIV:

```
<div id="ppplus"> </div>
```

3) Render Payment wall:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
 var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
 "approvalUrl": "'.$approval_url.'",
 "placeholder": "ppplus",
 "mode": "sandbox",
"country": "DE"
 });
</script>
```

Since I want to use this in a NativeScript application I cannot use the `script`-Tag. My workaround would be to import this (if possible) like an usual module.

What I tried:

```
import * as "https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/ppplus.min.js"
```

but he can't find the given module (which seems kinda obvious, since it is no installed module itself). Is there any other way to do this?

PS: If you know any other way to include the wall, feel free to tell me, it might be a better idea than mine :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find SDK for android/ios as this library is browser dependant, it will not work for you as Nativescript don't have DOM objects like browsers as i see many mouse events and other thinng

Comment: Thanks for that, how do you know, that there are DOM objects required? Sorry for the question, i am a newbie considering all this web-development stuff :D

Comment: Used `CTRL + F` for common browser dependant things like `window.(something)` or manipulating with DOM objects `document.(something)`

Comment: And there is basically no workaround for that? Or at least no expensive workaround for it?

Comment: Whole workaround would be quite rewriting which i think would be problematic best thing would be those SDK tools if they exists

Comment: There are many SDK-tools existing, but you gotta find one supporting Nativescript and thats not easy. There is a Nativescript-paypal plugin, but its only supported on Android devices... (sadly)

Comment: Btw. is there a way to add an external library via link? Or is this not supported for {N}

Comment: Probably it is but people won't be always on internet so it can fail if you are offline on mobile and at bigger libs not all people would be happy to download it for example