# Best way to integrate PayPal PLUS into NativeScript APP

Tags: typescript, paypal, nativescript

I am looking for a way to integrate PayPal PLUS into my NativeScript mobile Application. What I found was this (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf) which seems to provide no available NativeScript integration (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609151/import-ppplus-library-for-rendering-payment-wall-via-given-link-in-typescript/45609368?noredirect=1#comment78182015_45609368)).

There is a {N} plugin called [nativescript-paypal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-paypal), which is only supporting Android. But there has to be another way to integrate PayPal Payments into {N} applications besides using that plugin and building the iOS-Version yourself.

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: Does Apple allow PayPal integration in an app that's in the App Store? I doubt it.

Comment: Actually they do :) There is no need to integrate payments via in-App-Payments using the App Store

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. If you find an ios solution - pls shoot a quick note over. In the meantime, I'll take a look at it also.

Comment: Actually I am struggling with the {N}-Integration, but you can e.g. use [Braintree SDKs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4) in an Xcode Application. It seems quite easy to integrate and offers PayPal, AndroidPay/ApplePay and some other methods. Actually PayPal even tells you to consider using it when trying to integrate PayPay payments:

Comment: I've already got PayPal integrated using their web-pay API - so for me, if i can redirect the user to a web-page and pay by PayPal/Amazon - that works. Surprised Apple allows it but I guess I'll find out on a few days.